# Assigning CloudFront Aliases in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having a problem defining CloudFront CNAME aliases in my CloudFormation template. Here is where I attempt to define the CNAME aliases for the distribution. The below script fails to execute properly but works if I remove the 'aliases' element.

```
"LiveStreamingDistribution" : {
"Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
"Properties" : {
   "DistributionConfig" : {
       "CustomOrigin" : {
           "DNSName"              : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WowzaServerOriginServer", "PublicDnsName" ] },
           "HTTPPort"             : "80",
           "HTTPSPort"            : "443",
           "OriginProtocolPolicy" : "http-only"
       },
       "Enabled" : "true",
       "Comment" : "Live HTTP Streaming",
       "Aliases": ["cdn.cox7stream.com"]
    }
}
},
```

Here is a working template with no Aliases definition:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/streamresources/liveStreamPlatform/LiveStreamTemplateV0.0.0.1.txt

Here is the same template with the Aliases definition that fails to execute properly:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/streamresources/liveStreamPlatform/LiveStreamTemplateV0.0.0.2.txt

Answer (score 2):

Use "Origins" instead of "CustomOrigin".

See 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=419079